# Python only use mem-cached memory for process?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, parallel-processing, memcached

Is there some library I can import to make ALL my native python executions read and write local variables to a memcached instean? Thus using NO local memory (no RAM)?

Pretend I have the following machines:

`Machine0a` has 100GB memory dedicated to hosting my memcached 
`Machine0b` has 100GB memory dedicated to hosting my memcached 
`Machine0c` has 100GB memory dedicated to hosting my memcached 
`Machine1`  has .01GM memory, and a bunch of cores. 
`Machine2`  has .01GM memory, and a bunch of cores.

I basically want to be able to write the following scripts:

On `Machine1`, I have the following cron job run every hour:

```
import pylibmc
import onlyusememcached

#Have python make ALL process VARIABLES in memcached
#   with some unique name that only this program recognizes
really_big_number = 100000000 #-> THIS IS IN THE MEMCACHED 
#   Under the hood this is stored in memcached as    `Machine1ID.ProcessID.GlobalScopeID.really_big_number`

a = []
#   Under the hood `a` is stored in memcached as    `Machine1ID.ProcessID.GlobalScopeID.a`
for x in range(really_big_number):
    #   Under the hood `x` is stored in the memcached as `Machine1ID.ProcessID.GlobalScopeID.forloopScopeID.x``
    a.append([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

#Save `a` as a shared variable with a normal memcached call:
mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"], binary=True)
mc['SharedA'] = a
```

On `Machine2`, I have the following cron job run every hour + 5 min:

```
import pylibmc
import onlyusememcached
import numpy

#Go get my shared `a` from the memcached
mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"], binary=True)
a =  mc['SharedA']
#   `a` is now copied into memcached as `Machine2ID.ProcessID.GlobalScopeID.a`

b = numpy.cov(a) 
#   `b` is now stored into memcached as `Machine2ID.ProcessID.GlobalScopeID.b`
#   numpy operations ALL happen with ONLY memcached memory 
#   so Machine 2 doesn't need any memory of its own to perform the cov calculations
#   Machine 2 ONLY needs the processor
```

I want to be lazy and re-use regular python scripts which do all their own storage and retreival to memcached instead of the local machine. 
I want `onlyusememcached` module to be clever for me so that scope is maintained without collision for all machines and processes which import the module. 
I want to buy a pile of Machines dedicated to a large amount of memory.  
I want to buy a different pile of Machines dedicated to processing.

Does this module exist?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something or are you trying to use memcached as a replacement for your RAM?! I'm pretty sure there's no module for this as it would make things incredibly slow...

Comment: Well... the bottleneck for speed is the connection speed to the mem-cached. I understand the difference in speed of connecting directly to the ram in a machine VS connecting to the memcached -> however being able to do this allows for easy scaling of some large computations without having to be smart. Being smart is work and I don't want to work if I don't have too.

Comment: Offloading data to perform calculations on from memory that's connected straight to the CPU with *extremely* high bandwidth to networked memory is going to be a massive performance bottleneck. Especially considering that numpy makes use of low-level storage (a np array is stored as a C-style array, not as an array of python objects, so operations on the whole array are much cheaper). Imagine how slow it would be when adding network overhead..

Comment: I am willing to admit the slowness -> but If I can throw money at arbitrary code problems instead of my own time just so it works - it would be nice to use a quick `import` + $$ to do so. Tell me now to implement numpy.cov on a really really really big array -> without having to be smart and partition stuff into smaller work loads myself on some cluster, which I ahve to learn protocols. And after numpy.cov, I will want numpy.something else tomorrow  - etc.

Comment: If you're okay with that level of slowness, have you considered letting Python just start swapping memory to disk?

Comment: Multi node computation is not a python strong suit. You can probably whip something together with one of the python MPI implementations, but its going to take some knowledge and time. At some point hiring a decent programmer is going to be more cost-effective than throwing money at servers.

Comment: [Python has it's own overridable memory allocator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0445/)

Comment: @ppperry Does the custom memory allocator allow numpy to make use of it?

Comment: I'm not familar with numpy, but it is possible for other C code to use python's allocator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach to build this isn't actually that difficult. 
All I have to do is write a c library which overwrites the c memory allocation functions.

The python default memory allocation functions are here, and they all just use the native C memory allocation functions.

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html

The c default memory allocation functions are `malloc` and `free`:

And there of course exists the c library which implements memcached

http://docs.libmemcached.org/libmemcached.html

So all I have to do is make my own new `malloc` and `free` functions and import them correctly.

```
#define malloc(x) ....
#define free(x) ....
```

Which make use of the `libmemcached` instead of accessing the RAM

Comment: How are you planning to get your computer to treat Memcached as memory? I think that's going to require some really nasty low-level work, like modifying the kernel's page fault handler and recompiling your OS. This is probably going to take more expertise than what you were trying to avoid.

Comment: Also, don't forget Memcached is a cache. It evicts entries. You'll need to deal with eviction somehow.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'd guess whoever downvoted did so because this answer severely understates the difficulty of implementing these malloc/free functions, Memcached is a horrible tool for the job of using remote RAM as if it were local, and even with more appropriate tools, using remote RAM as local would be incredibly slow.

Comment: [Python has it's own overridable memory allocator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0445/)